# Tutorial/Blog for GroovyFx

Tags: groovy, hyperlink, javafx-2, groovyfx

I need links for blog, tutorials that covers GroovyFx. I have tried searching it on google, i'm not getting any useful tutorials. I need a full coverage of GroovyFx from top to bottom!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you want full coverage blog entries, or tutorials about GroovyFX for JavaFX 2.0?

GroovyFX ([according to the best page I can find](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyFX)) is an Alpha v0.1 release.

That page was created June 7th 2011

I think, you're probably asking too much for a full top to bottom blog

Indeed, the best I can find at this time, is [this interview page](http://fxexperience.com/2011/07/interview-with-the-developers-behind-groovyfx/)

Comment: Yup thanks for this link.. the interview page is the first one i came across and decided to see for GroovyFx :D once again thanks for the answer :D

Answer (score 1):

GroovyFX is fairly new, and as mentioned it is still in alpha state, though it is pretty complete based on the current JavaFX 2.0 Beta. Our plan is to GA release it as soon as possible after JavaFX 2.0 is GA'd. Currently, we are writing API documentation and doing performance tuning. No tutorials yet, at least none by Dean or me, though a few people have been using it for projects.

Comment: Dean just posted a blog about GroovyFX, http://pleasingsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/08/introducing-groovyfx-it-about-time.html. It might help understanding the APIs.